# Article choice regarding scientific relationships

Tags: articles

I am always confused which kind of article I should put in the following case:

This paper shows ***an/the*** inverse relationship between gravity and air density.

At first, "**the** inverse relationship" sounded correct to me but now I have no idea.
Any principle or rule of thumb behind this usage?

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly basic (famous last words) but, as a scientist, I would differentiate between the two as follows:

> This paper shows **the** inverse relationship between gravity and air
> density

Here what is implied is that it is already well known that an inverse relationship of this kind exists. Perhaps the formula is given in text books or a specific relationship has just been referred to. Hence one is writing about one particular relationship, so this requires the *definite* article when refering to its appearance in the paper. (It is perhaps difficult to see the context in which this would be used — more likely in a sentence such as “This paper shows *how to derive* the inverse relationship…”.)

> This paper shows **an** inverse relationship between gravity and air
> density

Here the implication is that there is *no* common understanding of or consensus on whether there is a relationship between gravity and air density. If there is a relationship its nature is unknown. So there may be many different types of relationship possible (direct, inverse, logarithmic), or none. Hence the use of the *indefinite* article in the sentence.

So, the answer to the poster’s question depends on the context.

Comment: An alternative reading for the variant with the definite article is that it is chosen because, having determined (to their satisfaction) that such a relationship obtains, the relationship is permanent, definite. 'This paper shows  the inverse relationship that exists between gravity and air density.' vs 'This paper shows that an inverse relationship exists between gravity and air density'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Yes. I am conscious of the limitations of my answer. One could also discuss cases where either article is possible. Consider Einstein's e=mc^2 equation. Normally one would say something like "In 19xx E published a paper describing the relationship between energy and matter". However in a historical account of the development of ideas, one might (especially if given to British understatement) write "...and then E realized there was a relationship between energy and matter." If the poster is not a native speaker, then understanding the subtleties of usage is not easy.

Comment: Putting all discussions above together, I kind of realize that correct article usage is extremely subtle depending on different kinds of nuances and connotations in the context. (I am not a native English speaker) Just one more question is that given this subtlety, even professionals cannot easily penalize or criticize your seemingly and slightly mistaken use of articles in your sentences unless it is very clear to everyone? Or can they easily detect the mistake or feel awkward about your articles in academic journals?

Comment: @joe — Don't be misled by my remarks to Edwin Ashworth. This site is really for advanced English language questions, not for relatively basic ones from non-native speakers. My answer is not a comprehensive analysis of the whole question, but it does, I hope, contain clear principles that can be used in most situations of the type you describe. You may come across odd subtleties in reading, as in any language. As for people's reaction to misuse, it varies. It will be noticed, however. When refereeing papers I personally always list corrections, because I would wish to be corrected myself.